# ZF2 Zend framework not calling global.php for Album tutorial application

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2

I have been getting an error: Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter"; no instance returned.

Tracing this down, I found that Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter is presented in global.php.  But, global.php is never being called or at least hasn't been called before module.php getserviceconfig() where the error is tripping.  Both testconfig.php.dist and application.config.php present global.php to the listener defintion.  But, global.php never executes.

Can someone please tell me why?  Definitions follow.

global.php

```
<?php
echo PHP_EOL . "Global.php executed." . PHP_EOL;
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=album.techmate.com',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

testconfig.php.dist

```
<?php

echo PHP_EOL . "TestConfig.php.dist executed." . PHP_EOL;
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Album', // <-- Add this line
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

application.config.php

```
<?php
echo PHP_EOL . "Application.config.php executed." . PHP_EOL;
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Album',                  // <-- Add this line
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

module.php just for completeness...

```
<?php

namespace Album;

use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;

class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface {

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
/*                'Zend\db\Adapter\Adapter' => function($sm) {
                    echo PHP_EOL . "SM db-adapter executed." . PHP_EOL;
                    $config = $sm->get('config');
                    $config = $config['db'];
                    $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter($config);
                    return $dbAdapter;
                },*/
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' => function($sm) {
                    echo PHP_EOL . "SM AlbumTable executed." . PHP_EOL;
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    echo PHP_EOL . "SM AlbumTableGateway executed." . PHP_EOL;
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                        return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }

}

?>
```

And the error...

```
TestConfig.php.dist executed.


Module.config.php executed.
PHPUnit 3.7.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\phpunit.xml.dist

......E
SM AlbumTable executed.

SM AlbumTableGateway executed.


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 8.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) AlbumTest\Model\AlbumTableTest::testGetAlbumTableReturnsAnInstanceOfAlbumTable
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:450
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php:50
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:726
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:843
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:487
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:442
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php:44
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:726
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:843
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:487
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:442
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:33
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Model\AlbumTableTest.php:149

FAILURES!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 9, Errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PHPUnit bootstrapping instructions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html#bootstrapping-your-tests), it looks like in `TestConfig.php.dist` the following line may be wrong:

```
'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
```

Change the line to:

```
'../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
```

If you had a `local.php` config file it also would likely not be loading.

Of course, if the directory structure is non-standard, change the line accordingly, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is absolutely correct.  I had just posted the response in the Zend forums and was about to post it here when I found your answer.  Your answer accesses zf2-tutorial/config/autoload which is probably the best case.  However, the tutorial reads to put it within Album/config/autoload.  In that case, the line should read as ../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php  Either would work, as long as you understand the structure and access the files where you store them.  One other note, I had to put a higher level node onto both global.php and local.php to match this i.e. myconfig.global.php.

Comment: I had to do: /config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php

Comment: @DominicWatson; note that the file path that you listed is an absolute path rather than a relative path, and it references a strange location. Typo perhaps? For those curious about paths: [paths explained](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/absolute-and-relative-paths-256350/#post1300204), [wikipedia on paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))

Answer (score 1):

I believe global.php is not being autoloaded because the naming of the file does not match:

```
'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
```

So if you name the file `myconfig.global.php` it should be picked up.

Comment: Well, that was a fair shot but, no, the result was the same.  I do thank you for your response...RG

Comment: I found that this was a necessary part of the total solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this problem but I am very disappointed in needing to do so.  Reading the ZF2 manual, I found a note that global.php and local.php are supposed to be merged with module.config.php by the ModuleManager.  From what I see, this should actually happen in ModuleManagerFactory but...

In any case, I manually added the global.php and local.php information into module.config.php.  That worked but, again, it should not be necesary.

As always, I'd be glad to receive a better answer than this.

I am including the manual reference for clarity.  It is from page 700.  Note that it also includes an error calling the files my.global.config.php and my.local.config.php.  I did actually try those names just in case but that did not work.

```
154.5 Default Configuration Options
The following options are available when using the default services configured by the ServiceManagerConfig
and ViewManager.
These configuration directives can go to the config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php files, or in the
module/<module name>/config/module.config.php configuration files. The merging of these configuration
files is done by the ModuleManager. It first merges each module’s module.config.php file, and then
the files in config/autoload (first the *.global.php and then the *.local.php files). The order of the
merge is relevant so you can override a module’s configuration with your application configuration. If you have both
a config/autoload/my.global.config.php and config/autoload/my.local.config.php, the
local configuration file overrides the global configuration.
```

Comment: This fixed my problems as well. However I cannot accept this as a solution. Were you able to find any workaround? We must find a proper solution :)

Comment: OK I think I found it :)

There is a wrong path written for config_glob_paths in TestConfig.php.dist 

If you count number of parent folders it turns out there are four and not three. So I needed to put 

'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            '../../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        )


Please let me know if this solves your problems as well.